# How to create Point object from XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an application that needs functionality for saving the x,y coordinates of an object so that upon starting the application a second time at a later date the application can search the previously found points for an image.

I have successfully created a method for writing an XML Document (which I think is formatted correctly) with the points the application has found.  Now I just need to read those points from the XML file back to a point object upon start-up.

I have found several examples of "how" to read XML from file, or answers to similar problems but for whatever reason I'm having trouble applying those answers to this situation.  I am interested in an explanation of how to pull the date element from xml and create a datatime object, as well as pull the x element and y element in each location element and put them into a new Point that I can then use.

This is what my XML document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FirstLookGameBox_XML>
  <location>
    <date>2014-10-15T00:00:00-06:00</date>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </location>
  <location>
    <date>2014-10-15T00:00:00-05:00</date>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </location>
  <location>
    <date>2014-10-15T00:00:00-04:00</date>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </location>
</FirstLookGameBox_XML>
```

Here's what I have for my code... obviously linq/xml and to be honest I'm not really sure what I'm doing with it.  Most answers out there just throw a block of code at you and don't explain what it means so I tried to take what I've found and use it for my own purposes but it's not working as I would hope.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string date;
int? x;
int? y;

var q = from b in xml.Descendants("location")
        select new
        {
            date = (string)b.Element("date"),
            x = (int?)b.Element("x"),
            y = (int?)b.Element("y"),
        };
```

I'm also wondering if the way I've formatted the XML document is correct?
My objective here is to find the last known locations for an image but only store the last 3 known locations.  If a fourth location is found I would replace the oldest last known location with the newest last known location.

Hopefully I've provided enough information for this to make sense.

Comment: Even if your code isn't working there is value in posting it - that way we won't give you suggestions that you've already tried.

Comment: Alright, one moment while I put it up here.

Comment: You would do well to tell us what behavior you actually are getting

Comment: That being said, It's been a while since I've used linq to xml, but I'm pretty sure that `b.Element("y")` returns an `XElement` object, and not your value.  I think you want `b.Element("y").Value` or something like that.

Comment: All I get are null values.  I know nothing about pulling data from XML and for the most part the answers I've run into floating around on the web aren't explaining why they are doing it how they are they just throw snippets of code out so I'm trial by firing hundreds of times and never find a resolve. :)

Comment: @Fama_Sicura All you get where?   are you printing these values? are you viewing them in the debugger?   If so, can you post a screenshot?   When I copy your code and XML exactly, I'm getting 0s for X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait wait wait, are you expecting this x and y declared in the following snippet to have any value?

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string date;
int? x;
int? y;
```

you're not actually setting those to anything, and if you were, it wouldn't make any sense, because you have many `x`s and `y`s in your XML.  If you want to access the x and the y that you're actually storing, do this.

```
foreach (var obj in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.x);  // or however you want to see your input
    Console.WriteLine(obj.y);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a null value for my x variable.  I'm assuming I replace the x = (int?)b.Element("x"), with your x = int.Parse(b.Element("x").Value).

Comment: The LINQ query is returning a collection of an anonymous type - it's not going to set `x` to anything.   You need to iterate through the returned collection and check the `date`, `x` and `y` properties of each object in the collection.

Comment: @Fama_Sicura  What does your output look like?

Comment: `(int?)b.Element("x")` is legal - it causes an explicit conversion to `Nullable<int>`.  The conversion calls the `.Value` property before returning.

Comment: regardless of what I do here my variable are not being changed by the linq expression.  Nothing occurs when it runs through that.  

I don't so much care how I get the values out of the XML or by what means that is done... I just want to be able to do it.. It's one of the reasons I didn't want to put my C# code down because I figured everyone would become fixated on how to fix what I had, instead of just giving an example of how to do it.

My main object is to learn how this is done so that I may implement the idea across my application and continue to improve upon it in the future.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound snooty.. just that for as much looking as I've done I've yet to find an explanation for the steps to pull data from a specific element of XML and relate that data to an object within my code.

Comment: @Fama_Sicura You still haven't told us what output you're getting, and how you're getting it

Comment: @Fama_Sicura I've just copied your code and ran it, and it worked as expected.  nothing was null

Comment: @SamIam, ok.  This helped me to understand what was going on in the whole process.  The x/y was being populated previously, as you'd said, but I wasn't seeing it because of how I'd formatted writing it to Console.  I appreciate sticking with me here and helping me better understand what's going on.  I've still got some work to do to get it to do EXACTLY what I want, but your answer is correct for what I'd asked.  Thanks again.  You've added another weapon to my arsenal.